# EBook::EPUB.pm add_navpoint use

Tags: perl, epub

I have one large `.xhtml` file consisting of many chapters. There are `div` tags with e.g. `id="article2"` on some of them.  I am now trying to make an ebook out of it.  [EBook::EPUB](http://p3rl.org/EBook%3a%3aEPUB) is a nice package that helps greatly.

And I have most of it working well. Alas, the following does not work:

```
for (my $cnt=1; $cnt<=$#chapters; ++$cnt) {
  $epub->add_navpoint(
                      label => 'Chapter '.$cnt.": $memotitles[$cnt]",
                      id => 'article'.$cnt,
                      content => 'text.xhtml',
                      play_order => $cnt );
}
```

When I open the epub file in iBooks, it shows me the labels, but clicking on any of them does not move me to the right page in the epub file.

I know that it is possible to get ids from a book where each chapter is its own `.xhtml` file.  alas, is it possible to get ids to reference waypoints (chapters) from inside the same `.xhtml` file? Or do I really have to break my large `.xhtml` file into many smaller ones?

Advice appreciated.

Comment: What module are you using to parse the file? Can you give a very short example of the file and the code you are using to parse it?

Comment: I would be happy to share it (post a new question and let me know).  a good sample is http://blog.64p.org/entry/2012/11/21/075948 .  however, I don't think it would help on this question. think content of "...<h1 id="article1">tom</h1> ... lots ...<h1 id="article2">jerry</h1> ..." and now you want to place waypoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"content" property should have id of the element in the xhtml page. So something like this should work:

```
for (my $cnt=1; $cnt<=$#chapters; ++$cnt) {
  $epub->add_navpoint(
                      label => 'Chapter '.$cnt.": $memotitles[$cnt]",
                      id => 'article'.$cnt,
                      content => 'text.xhtml#article' . $cnt,
                      play_order => $cnt );
}
```

Comment: additional advice: iBooks is a much slower reader if a text is not broken into individual files.  so, breaking still has the speed advantage.